# Effects of ammonia fumes on computer hardware

Tags: terminal, physical-environment

At my company we have recently started printing film for use in our flexible packaging conversion operations. The printing process utilizes inks with a pungent ammonia fume (I think it's used as a transfer medium).

We are considering adding a computer terminal to the press room, but are curious whether the hardware will be corroded too quickly to make it a viable solution.

The terminal will have the standard tower/monitor/keyboard/mouse and possibly a printer down the road. We will likely use plastic covers to protect the keyboard from dirt/ink/grease.

The press room is well ventilated, and though the fumes are strong they are still low enough to provide a safe work environment for us humans.

Based on articles about computer cleaning, I know that ammonia is not recommended due to its corrosive tendencies, especially to monitors. However, that seems to relate to direct contact in liquid form, not contact in gaseous form.

**Will the ammonia fumes passing through the ventilation of the computer damage the internal components? How will it effect the life of the hardware? Is this physical environment not recommended at all, or will the effects be nominal enough to make do?**

Comment: People are very sensitive to ammonia.  If the odor isn't so bad that people find it a problem, it probably isn't concentrated enough to affect the equipment.  Think of it as the computers using people the way miners used canaries.

Comment: @fixer1234 Good point, that's my hunch as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say there is a "pungent ammonia fume."  However, this doesnt necessarily mean there is ammonia, or significant quantities.  The best course of action is to talk to the ink manufacturer.  They will be able to tell you what the effects would be.

Comment: I can verify that it is in fact ammonia. The ppm is unknown, but as a baseline it is below irritation levels for humans. I called the ink manufacturer but they couldn't answer my question either. They did mention that their lab has a computer that works fine (who knows what IT has dealt with). I will assume that this application is fine, and hope my manager is ok with anecdotal instead of scientific support.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the room is well ventilated it should be fine, however, like Keltari said, you should ask the computer manufacturer. It would help to know the computer brand and model. I may be able to give you further help then. Most newer models of computers do a fair job of keeping the computer clean and ventilated with the use of fans, however you will need to air it out every now and then if it has a tower. Most all-in-ones are meant not to be opened, though. However all-in-ones are not usually meant for business use. Just remember never to clean a computer with a liquid.

I say go for it, very low fumes shouldn't hurt it.

Comment: We haven't purchased a terminal yet, so I cannot elaborate on which make or model this will be, though we will likely avoid a laptop or all-in-one.

Comment: That's ok. I saw your post on the above answer, and if it's so low to the point it doesn't affect humans, it should be fine.